# Convert iterator of string slice to Vector<String>

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and just wondering if there is a shorter or more idiomatic way to convert an iterator of `&str` to a `Vec<String>`

```rust
let contents = fs::read_to_string(config.filename)?;

let la : Vec<String> = contents.lines().map( |x| String::from(x) ).collect();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think reading the full file in a string is a bit unnecessary. Instead you can read the file line by line and collect them like that.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

let file = File::open(config.filename)?;
let la = io::BufReader::new(file)
    .lines()
    .collect::<Result<Vec<String>, _>>()?;
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope. That is the idiomic way. You could use function pointers to shorten your code by the tiniest amount.

```rust
let la: Vec<String> = contents.lines().map(String::from).collect();
```